# A fast algorithm to minimize a pseudo Diophantine equation

Tags: algorithm, minimum, number-theory

We're looking for an algorithm to solve this problem in under O(N).

given two real numbers a and b (without loss of generality you can assume they are both between 0 and 1)
Find an integer n between -N and N that minimizes the expression:

|a n - b - round(a n - b)|

We have thought that the Euclidean Algorithm might work well for this, but can't figure it out.  It certainly looks like there should be much faster ways to do this than via an exhaustive search over integers n.

Note: in our situation a and b could be changing often, so fixing a and b for a lookup table is possible, it gets kind of ugly as N can vary as well.  Haven't looked in detail into the lookup table yet, to see how small we can get it as a function of N.

Comment: If you are planning on testing k different *n*s then I can provide a solution that guarantees that |a n - b - round(a n - b)| < 1/k.

Comment: We are searching over all n integer such that |n|<= N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be looking for something like [continued fractions](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction)...

How are they related? Suppose you can substitute b with a rational number b1/b2. Now you are looking for integers n and m such that an-b1/b2 is approximately m. Put it otherwise, you are looking for n and m such that (m+(b1/b2))/n = (mb2+b1)/nb1, a rational number, is approximately a. Set a1 = mb2+b1 and a2 = nb1. Find values for a1 and a2 from a continued fractions approximation and solve for n and m.

Another approach could be this:

1. Find a good rational approximations for a and b: a ~ a1/a2 and b ~ b1/b2.
2. Solve n(a1/a2)-(b1/b2) = m for n and m.

I'm not too sure it would work though. The accuracy needed for a depends on n and b.

Comment: I'm sure he knows what a continued fraction is, but how does this help, exactly?

Comment: You don't see the similarity to finding rational approximations for real numbers? I'm too tired to work out a decent argument now.

Comment: @JoniSalonen Finding rational approximation != solution here. Even if x/y is approximately equal to a, |y*a-round(y*a)| might still be high. Eg: a= 0.1111111110874642873287.... x=1, y=9 is a good approximation. But |9*a - round(9*a)| is roughly equal to 1.

Comment: Edited the answer to make the idea clearer. @ElKamina wouldn't |9*a - round(9*a)| be more like .0000000002128214140417 rather than 1?

Answer (score 1):

You are effectively searching for the integer N that makes the expression `aN - b` as close as possible to an integer. Are `a` and `b` fixed? If yes you can pre-compute a lookup table and have O(1) :-)

If not consider looking for the N that makes `aN` close to `I + b` for all integers `I`.

Comment: a and b are not fixed unfortunately.  We had thought of that.  We have thought about building up N lookup tables for N small, but that is trading O(N) space for O(1) speed, we generally don't like that approach, but that's our fallback position.

Comment: Did you try plotting the equation and trying some heuristics?

Comment: Nope, not too interested in heuristics for this one.

Comment: This can at least provide some insights. Are `a` and `b` reals or floating point integers with limited precision?

Comment: probably floats, possibly doubles.  This is stuff to be implemented on a computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute a continued fraction for the ratio a/b. You can stop when the denominator is greater than `N`, or when your approximation is good enough.

```
// Initialize:
double ratio = a / b;
int ak = (int)(ratio);
double remainder = ratio - ak;

int n0 = 1;
int d0 = 0;

int n1 = ak;
int d1 = 1;

do {
    ratio = 1 / remainder;
    ak = (int)ratio;
    int n2 = ak * n1 + n0;
    int d2 = ak * d1 + d0;
    n0 = n1;
    d0 = d1;
    n1 = n2;
    d1 = d2;
    remainder = ratio - ak;
} while (d1 < N);
```

The value for `n` you're looking for is `d0` (or `d1` if it is still smaller than `N`).

This doesn't necessarily give you the minimum solution, but it will likely be a very good approximation.

Comment: Need minimum.  Why is d0 or d1 the number I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

First, let us consider a simpler case where b=0 and 0 < a < 1. F(a,n) = |an-round(an)|

Let step_size = 1

```
Step 1. Let v=a
Step 2. Let period size p = upper_round( 1/v ).
Step 3. Now, for n=1..p, there must be a number i such that F(v,i) < v.
Step 4. v = F(v,i), step_size = stepsize * i
Step 5. Go to step 2
```

As you can see you can reduce F(v, *) to any level you want. Final solution n = step_size.

Comment: if b = 0, then let n = 0 (n is between -N and N inclusive) and we get the expression is zero.  I assume you're looking at the sub problem where n is between 1 and N inclusive?  Could you describe what it is your algorithm is doing?  Looks like some sort of continued fraction expression?

Comment: @John this gives a solution between 1 and infinity. Now I saw your question in detail, and yes, it wouldn't work for your problem.